# preg_replace using the replaced text as variable name

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have several variables like these:

```
$foo = '123';  
$bar = 'bqwe';
```

I need to replace `{$foo}` and `{$bar}` in a string with the variables.

```
preg_replace('~\{\$(.*)?\}~sU', ${'\\1'}, $string);
```

This doesn't work.

PS: The regex might not be correct. I haven't tested it with several variables like `{$asd}` `{$bbb}`. I am testing with one variable now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the regex more specific. Make it match for \w+ word characters.

And then you were on the right track, but need the [`/e` eval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) modifier to make the variable lookup in the local scope work:

```
= preg_replace('~\{\$(\w+?)\}~sUe', '${"$1"}', $string);
```

So when it matches `foo` the relacement string becomes `${"foo"}` which then is used as expression. (Whereas in your original code it was incorrectly tried before the regex executed.)

Comment: preg_replace_eval modifier is deprecated nowadays as of PHP 5.5.0

Comment: @sasha Which is what the linked manual page already says. The very `/e`-deprecation was intended to avoid interpretation of unfiltered input; which the above example is not susceptible to.

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop:

```
php > $s='blah blah {$foo} blah blah {$bar} blah blah {$foo} blah {$bar} blah';
php > $foo='FOO';
php > $bar='BAR';
php > while (preg_match('~\{\$(.*)?\}~sU', $s, $m)) $s=str_replace($m[0],$$m[1],$s);
php > echo $s;
blah blah FOO blah blah BAR blah blah FOO blah BAR blah
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I think u want to remove the text which exist in some variable 
then u can do it like

```
$foo = '123';  
$bar = 'bqwe';                      
$str= preg_replace("/".$foo ."/", '', $str, 1);
$str= preg_replace("/".$bar ."/", '', $str, 1);
```